# The percentage of occurrences of a field per ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making a website for a game as a hobby and I want to add a win percentage for every champion in it. I track every match in my DB and the outcome column can be 0 or 1 for loss or win. I am using MySql. I want my outcome table to be like this:

```
ChampID | Wins | Loss | Percentage
12        1      1      50%
13        2      0      100%
```

My Matches table looks like this:

```
MatchID | ChampID | PlayerID | MatchOutcome
1         12        1231       1
2         12        1414       0
3         13        1341       1
4         13        1512       1
```

So the champion with ID 12 will have 50% win rate while 13 will have 100%.

I have been trying unions and joins but I couldn't get them right, this is the closest I have come.

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Matches WHERE (MatchOutcome LIKE "0")) AS Loss,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Matches WHERE (MatchOutcome LIKE "1")) AS Win, 
(SELECT (Win/(Win+Loss))*100 ) AS Percentage
```

This method seems the most promising as I would also like to be able to sort further by PlayerID.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do some simply math to do this. No reason to get creative with joins and subqueries:

```
 SELECT sum(matchoutcome)/count(matchid) FROM Matches where PlayerID = 12;
```

Or, for each player in a list:

```
SELECT playerID, sum(matchoutcome)/count(matchid) FROM Matches GROUP BY playerID;
```

You can do your conversion to a percentage here too:

```
SELECT playerID, (sum(matchoutcome)/count(matchid))*100 FROM Matches GROUP BY playerID;
```

To get out Wins and Losses in separate columns:

```
SELECT playerID, 
    sum(matchOutcome) as Wins,
    Count(matchid) - sum(matchOutcome) as Losses,
    (sum(matchoutcome)/count(matchid))*100 
FROM Matches 
GROUP BY playerID;
```

Comment: fair and simple solution. and it can be used with group by to generalize. Its interesting to see people downvoting a clear answer

Comment: Oh yea... I dunno about the downvotes. Perhaps I monkeyed something in there or misunderstood the question, but it seemed straightforward. The only thing I was thinking about adding is that `IF()` or a `CASE` statement would be another technique, but since matchoutcome is a boolean, there isn't a need for them.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for this answer! Exactly what I was looking for, appreciate the effort! Tested and everything works!

Comment: @Djinnes Glad it helped!